# How to handle localized exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I always seem to come to a cross road where I don't exactly know how to handle an exception without re-throwing to the caller.

Is there a better way to handle the below situation?

```
private DataHandler retrieveFromGridFS(ObjectId id) throws IOException
{
    GridFS gridFS = new GridFS(getDBReference());        
    GridFSDBFile out = gridFS.find(id);

    File temp = File.createTempFile(
            (String)out.getMetaData().get("productName"), 
            (String)out.getMetaData().get("productType"));

    out.writeTo(temp);

    return new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(temp));        
}
```

The above `private` method can throw an `IOException`.

Making use of this method like so:

```
public DataHandler retrieveProduct(String productId) throws IOException
{
    ObjectId id = new ObjectId(productId);
    DataHandler handler = null;

    try
    {
        handler = retrieveFromGridFS(id);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        logger.error(ex);
        throw new IOException("A problem occurred retrieving product.");
    }

    return handler;
}
```

I'm forced to re-throw so that I don't risk returning null.

Comment: don't throw away the original exception tho, makes debugging from log files much more difficult use `throw new IOException("A problem occurred retrieving product.", ex);`

Comment: +1; definitely--erasing underlying causes is a bane of debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends.

For one thing, do you really want to percolate an `IOException` to the upper layers, or do  you want to encapsulate the various exceptions that can occur at the lower layers in an application-specific exception?

Do you need to be able to recover from this exception? If not, is a `RuntimeException` more appropriate? (Even if you *do* need the exception to be recoverable, are you operating in an environment that provides for declarative exception handling at a high level?)

Would it make more sense to use a `NullObject` pattern to avoid returning a null?

(Etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, catch the exception if you can **respond to the event that occurred**.
Ex. let's say you have code to retry connections upon failure.  Then you might have a loop which catches IOException and retries x times.  The caller above doesn't care about the underlying failures.

When an exception occurs that you can't handle, you don't wouldn't it.  Essentially you're passing the buck.

Lately I've tended to avoid rethrowing exceptions as others exc objects in most cases.  I've found through experience it doesn't really add value most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

What? Looks to me like `retrieveProduct` is just a convenience function to do whatever `retrieveFromGridFS` does but with a String as an identifier instead of an ObjectId. So shouldn't the set of exceptions it can raise just be the same as that of `retrieveFromGridFS`?

Comment: that's what I'm showing in my example - I'm not sure as to what you're trying to say?

Comment: oh I see, I didn't realize `retrieveProduct` was private.

Comment: it's not, `retrieveFromGridFS` is.